# How do I pass 'emcc' options through 'emcmake cmake/emmake make'?

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten, emmake, emcmake

I have a CMake project (C++) that I want to make available in JavaScript through WebAssembly. To configure it, I use `emcmake cmake` and to build it `emmake make`. I can compile parts successfully, when I do it manually:

```sh
emcc --bind test.cpp
```

But  I want to profit from the advantages of `emmake`. I need the parameter `--bind` for `emcc`. `emmake` does not add it by default, which results in an error:

```
error: undefined symbol: _embind_register_function (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
```

So, how do I add it, when building with `emmake make`? Can I pass it to `emmake`? Or can I add something to my `CMakeLists.txt`?

---

MCRE:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyTest)
add_executable(mytest test.cpp)
```

`test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "emscripten/bind.h"

using namespace emscripten;

std::string getText()
{
    return "Hello there from C++!";
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    function("getText", &getText);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out, that you can pass the `emcc` options from within the `CMakeLists.txt` file, by using [`set_target_properties(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html):

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyTest)
add_executable(mytest test.cpp)
set_target_properties(mytest PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--bind")
```

This approach works for nearly all paramters, except the `-o` parameter to control the output files:

- If you want to change the name of the output, change the name of the target.
- If you want to change the directory of the output, change the executable output path with `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH subdir/for/emscripten)` before executing `add_executable(...)`
- If you want to change the file type of the output, change the executable suffix with `set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".mjs")` according to your [needs](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html) before executing `add_executable(...)`